# How to disable package used by external document?

Tags: macros, packages, external-files

Doxygen uses its own `doxygen.sty` style file, but I'd like to keep the style of my document where I want to put the Doxygen's output. So I'd prefer to somehow to turn of its settings. For example, using `let` command I can keep old defenitions of commands that are being redefined by `renewcommand`. But what about unloading package (i.e. `sectsty`) or somehow disable its commands like `allsectionsfont`?

**EDIT:**
I am trying to avoid any modification of `doxygen.sty` because it is autogenerated, so will be overwritten next time I change my sources and therefore will need to update the docs generated by Doxygen.

**EDIT 2:**
The `-w` option of `doxygen` does what it exactly stated to: writes header, footer, and style to the files specified on the command line. What all these names correspon to is... well, consider the following structure of the final document (i.e. `refman.tex`) the Doxygen tool produces:

1. header;
2. body;
3. footer;
4. Plus, styles that are `usepackage`d in the *header*.

What I struggle for is the *body* part of the document as *header* / *footer* I could provide myself, after all. I want to keep the textual structure of the document, i.e. chapters and `input`ted files generated for each of the source files, `class`, `struct`, etc.

Also, there still remains the problem of redefenition of several commands (such as `paragraph`, `subparagraph`) inside the Doxygen's style file. I want to disable them to keep the style of my main document consistent.

Comment: Is there any reason for not making a backup and modifying the contents of that `.sty` file? I never used Doxygen but shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @percusse See the **EDIT** section of my question.

Comment: I found [this option](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/config.html#cfg_latex_header) in the documentation for a particular preamble. It seems that it writes its own preamble if you don't provide any. Also [this](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/doxygen_usage.html) looks relevant for selecting the style file.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for you responses. See the **EDIT 2** section, please.

Answer (score 5):

If it's `doxygen.sty` that loads `sectsty`, for instance, it's sufficient to write in the document preamble

```
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@sectsty.sty}{}
\newcommand{\allsectionsfont}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

before `\usepackage{doxygen}`. In this way LaTeX will think that `sectsty` has already been loaded when it finds the corresponding request when processing `doxygen.sty`. When `\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}`, say, is found in `doxygen.sty` LaTeX will have available only the definition above and so the command will have no effect.

Comment: If `doxygen` then uses any `secsty` commands, then these will be undefined…

Comment: @Seamus It's quite difficult to tell more about the problem without some example. But one can augment the code in my answer to make the relevant commands into no-ops.

Answer (score 1):

This attends to Seamus' comment, hopefully.

```
\usepackage{afterpackage}
\makeatletter
% \@namedef{ver@sectsty.sty}{} 
\AfterPackage{sectsty}{\let\allsectionsfont\@gobble}
% Do the same for all the commands you wish to disable, but you have to know 
% the arguments the commands expect.
\makeatother
```